# Why django hashers are using assert?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a question regarding Django implementation of hashers. All of them implement `verify` method and are doing `assert algorithm == self.algorithm`.

I know that assertions can be disabled through passing the flag `-O` to the Python interpreter on production code.

For example, `BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher` implements `verify` like that:

```py
def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 2)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt)
    return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)
```

Is `assert` statement is meant to be used only during the development phase? Or there are other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the years, I've grown to add asserts in my code as well, similar to this.

When used like this, having your code raise an `AssertionError` instead of some side-effect error resulting in the expected condition not being met can help speedup debugging.

Personally, I don't see a problem with these `asserts` going into production, but that's a choice to make based on the individual use-case, and how your code is being used, maintained, etc.

Comment: I would add that you use `assert` in a place where you want to make sure you have reached a certain state, before proceeding. In this case, you want to make sure the correct `algorithm` is being used to encode the given password. You'd rather crash (something bad happened if the algorithm wasn't set correctly) than make a wrong password check.

Answer (score 0):

asserts shouldn't be used in production, depends if the code is optimized for production.

**asserts are striped out of pyo files** The upshot of this is the code as tested is not as deployed(if optimized). This may catch a developer unawares who is using asserts to raise and prevent further execution in development to protect an upstream call. This would not be protected in production.